# moving from rds to dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

have the following fields in RDS

```
id auto increment
creationDate datetime
status string
reason string
description string
customerID string
```

there are multiple records for the customerID + creationDate, so I am not able to use creationDate as sort key. The status field combo with customerID won't work as customer can have the duplicate record for same status. If I use the id field I can't auto increment as dynamoDB doesn't allow that? What are my options here? How should my ddb table look like?

Answer (score 3):

The key to DynamoDB is [knowing your access patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach). You haven't stated how you plan to query the data, so I can't advise on the overall design, but here is what you can do in order to have a unique primary key.

Do you really need auto-incrementing IDs? If not, consider using a UUID for all new data. Then you could use the ID field as the partition key; you could also use `customerId` as the partition key and `id` as the sort key.

If you must have auto-incrementing IDs, then you should store your `creationDate` in DynamoDB as an [ISO 8061](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string. Then, you can append a random UUID to the end of `creationDate` to avoid key collisions. This will allow you to use `customerId` and `creationDate` as the primary keys, and you are still able to query using the date (but instead of checking for equality, you should use the [`begins_with`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) function).

Finally, you can introduce a new field specifically to ensure uniqueness. You could call it simply `rangeKey`, and it would be a randomly generated UUID that you could use with any other field as the partition key. You can still have your sequential ID field (and create a GSI for querying it, if you want).

I've presented 3 solutions, but they are really all the same—find a way to add a UUID to your primary key.